# No se pudo cargar el tipo 'Proyecto.MvcApplication'

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Me salta al intentar iniciar el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Error del analizador
>   Descripción: Error al analizar el recurso requerido para dar servicio
>   a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error de análisis específicos
>   y modifique el archivo de código fuente en consecuencia.
>
> Mensaje de error del analizador: No se pudo cargar el tipo
>   'Proyecto.MvcApplication'.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 1: `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"Inherits="Proyecto.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`
>
> Archivo de origen: /global.asax Línea: 1

Mi proyecto es uno nuevo basado en otro antiguo, no se exactamente que falla ahi porque MvcAplication existe.

**global.ajax.cs**

```
namespace Proyecto
{

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log4net.config")));               
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();               
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            // Register your MVC controllers.
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

            builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).As<IIdentity>();

            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application shutdown

            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

No comprendo que puede estar sucediendo, ¿las referencias estarán corruptas? ¿Algún conflicto interno con algún elemento?
Si el elemento no encontrado existe y se encuentra en el lugar especificado en el error. Al compilar o recompilar la solución no me muestra ningún error, pero en el momento que ejecuto el IIS express para visualizar la web me salta un mensaje de error en la compilación.

¿De que puede venir ese error?

Comment: Verifica si la clase `MvcApplication` esta en el namespace `Proyecto`

Comment: @Einer Si, como ves en la edición se encuentra dentro, ¿Puede ser un problema de ensamblado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que tenia dos proyectos vinculados en una misma solución con diferentes Frameworks, la solución ha sido:

1. **Click derecho** en los proyectos y pulsar **propiedades**.
2. En la pestaña **Aplicación** seleccionar en **Plataforma de destino** el mismo framework.
3. **Reiniciar**.

Esto soluciona el error y ejecuta correctamente la web.